# Handling Razor Dropdowns for auto load values

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have two dropdowns in the view but one relies on the selected value from the other. But how could i load values into the second dropdown after selecting a value from the other? The second dropdown should load values basing on the id selected from the other dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label asp-for="BankId" class="control-label col-xs-2"></label>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <select class="form-control" asp-for="BankId" asp-items=@bank>
   <option>--- select bank ---</option></select>
   </div>
   </div>

 <div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="BankBranchId" class="control-label col-xs-2"></label>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<select class="form-control" asp-for="BankBranchId" asp-items=@bankbranches>
<option>--- select bank branch ---</option></select>
</div>
</div>
```

BankBranch should fill values basing on the bank selected from up

Comment: try out this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-one-DropDownList-based-on-another-DropDownList-selected-value-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: use jQuery ajax send back select Id to controller, then return JSON result and set another dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is example for bank and branches.
you can try out something

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
            <title>Index</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.bank, Model.bank, "Please select", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();" })
                <br/>
                <br/>

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.branches, Model.branches, "Please select", new { disabled = "disabled" })
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            }
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    if ($("#bank option").length > 1) {
                        $("#bank").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }

                    if ($("#branches option").length > 1) {
                        $("#branches").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }

                    if ($("#bank").val() != "" && $("#branches").val() != "") {
                        var message = "Bank: " + $("#CountryId option:selected").text();
                        message += "\nbranck: " + $("#StateId option:selected").text();
                        alert(message);
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       // populate bank values
        foreach (var bankent in entities.bank)
        {
            model.bank.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = bankent.bank, Value = bankent.id.ToString() });
        }
        return View(model);
    }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int? bank)
        {

          // populate bank values
            foreach (var bankent in entities.bank)
            {
                model.bank.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = bankent.bank, Value = bankent.id.ToString() });
            }

            if (bank.HasValue)
            {
                //populate branches based on bank id
                foreach (var state in branches)
                {
                    model.branches.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = state.branches, Value = state.StateId.ToString() });
                }

            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

for more detail check out [Populate one DropDownList based on another DropDownList selected value in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-one-DropDownList-based-on-another-DropDownList-selected-value-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)